# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. **SwapChain** было nullptr

Tags: c++, directx

Я новичок в программировании на C++ и перед мной стоит задача научиться пользоваться DirectX. Я уже знаю Java и мне не много надо было понять, что бы освоить С++. В интернете русскоязычные вроде не писали об такой проблеме (не нашел), то что англоязычные писали не помогло, или я не понял что они имели ввиду. Вот мой код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "d3d11.h"

HRESULT                 hr = NULL;
HINSTANCE               hInst = nullptr;
HWND                    hWnd = nullptr;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
ID3D11Device*           d3dDevice = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    ImmediateContext = nullptr;
IDXGISwapChain*         SwapChain = nullptr;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* RenderTargetView = nullptr;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       featureLevel;

void Render();
void initDX();

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR 
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    initDX();
    Render();
}


void Render()
{
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.9f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    ImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTargetView, ClearColor);

    SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}

void initDX()
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = 1280;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = 720;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    if(FAILED(hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, driverType, 
    NULL,D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG , NULL, NULL, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, 
    &SwapChain, &d3dDevice, &featureLevel, &ImmediateContext)))
        return;

    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    if (FAILED(hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), 
    (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer))) //здесь пишет о исключении
        return;

    hr = d3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, 
    &RenderTargetView);
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    ImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &RenderTargetView, 0);
}
```

Я так понял что я не реализовал переменную, но она должна реализовываться с методом D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(), но видимо не прав. В чем ошибка?

Comment: @Abyx Трудноразличимый авторский комментарий в коде утвердает, что падение происходит в `initDX`, а не в `Render`, что говорит о том ошибки в `initDX` формально не зафиксировано, но до `Render` дела не доходит.

Comment: Если я не дал какой то нужной информации, скажите, может дам ответ